# Determine row and column of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` displaying many items in a single section, wrapping over several rows, using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.

Is there a simple way to determine the actual row and column as displayed of a given `UICollectionViewCell`?

In the example image below, I'm looking for the row & column:
[image]

This is just an example - in the actual app I don't know how many columns there are. I realise I could calculate by knowing the cell width, collection view insets and spacing, but I was hoping there was another method that would give me the answer.

Comment: what about indexPathForCell: ?

Comment: No see my answer to @hacker2007

Comment: Did you solve your problem already? If yes, please mark the post that helped you or show us your solution.

Comment: No - see my answer to your question.

Answer (score 6):

you can retrieve the indexPath calling:

```
NSIndexPath *path = [myCollectionView indexPathForCell: cell];
```

if each row contains the same number of items

```
NSInteger itemsPerRow = 2;
NSInteger row = path.item / itemsPerRow;
NSInteger column = path.item % itemsPerRow;
```

Comment: No… that gives the the `section` (which is 0 as there's only one section) and `item` (the index of the item within the section.

Comment: I should have been clearer… I don't know how many in cells in the row. I was hoping for a simple way without having to calculate it.